# A/OpenGLRenderer: Error: Ambient Index Buffer overflow!!! used 338, total 298

Tags: android

When I upgrade support version from `23.2.1` to `25.4.0`, the page which has animations will crash.

> A/OpenGLRenderer: Error: Ambient Index Buffer overflow!!! used 338,
>   total 298

Answer (score 0):

I found reason.

CoordinatorLayout above 24 changed logic about "onMeasure", it won't measure child which is GONE.